# Display progress bar while uploading image to Amazon server in Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to display a `progress bar` while uploading an image to the `Amazon server.` Everything works fine, just that the progress bar is not visible when the image is being uploaded to the server. This is what I have tried so far.

`My Activity`

```
cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              //Take the picture for the first time.

               photoFileName += RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5) + ".jpg";
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName));

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
    });



  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

    // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

          Uri takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
          Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getPath());

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            takenImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);

         try {
                AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_SECRET_KEY));
                byte[] contentBytes = bos.toByteArray(); 

                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes);

                Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length);

                ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                objectMetadata.setContentLength(contentLength);

                PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest =
                        new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME,
                                photoFileName, is, objectMetadata);

             //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

              // progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

  }
```

This is what I have done so far. While uploading the `image` to the `server` the `phone screen` goes black(nothing works at this time) and returns to normal after like 10 seconds.

Comment: Consider doing the upload part in an AsyncTask.. Your Ui thread is probably getting blocked that is why u are getting black screen..In AsynckTask there is a method called  onProgressUpdate which can be used for ur need..Comment if you need eg

Comment: Hey @sunilsunny!! Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Did as you said and it works fine now..

Comment: @sunilsunny hey! I am getting the progress bar and everything works fine The problem is that once the image is captured it does not display in Image view, only on a few Samsung devices.

Comment: What is the size of this images ..It might be too large.Consider using Picasso,glide or universal image loader for this purpose.These libraries will do all the hard work for you.. Ask a different question if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

for showing progessbar

```
  private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

  private void showProgress() {
    if (isShowProgressDialog) {
        mProgressDialog = Util.getProgressDialog(activity);
    }
}
```

for hidding progress bar

```
 private void dismissProgress() {
    if (isShowProgressDialog) {
        Util.dismissDialog(activity, mProgressDialog);
    }
}

 public static ProgressDialog getProgressDialog(Context c) {
    //ProgressDialog mProgressDialog=new ProgressDialog(c);
    MyCustomProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new MyCustomProgressDialog(c);
    //mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    return mProgressDialog;
}
```